# What was St Paul's age at the time of his conversion and what was his age when he died?

Tags: bible, paul-apostle, missions

I think that there are no direct answers for this.
I would like to know the age of the Apostle St Paul when he encountered Jesus on the road to Damascus and how long he lived after that.

Answer (score 5):

It is somewhat impossible to know for sure how old St Paul was at the time of his conversion and death.

The Apostle Paul according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_the_Apostle) was born between the years of 5 BC and 5 AD. Most websites place his birth between the years 3-5 AD.

As for the Apostle's conversion, it seems to have occurred between the years 33-36 AD. Most websites favor the year 33 AD.

And finally, St Paul died as a martyr between the years 62-67 AD.

Thus St Paul was around 30 years of age at the moment of his conversion and 60 years of age at his death.

Sources:

[Paul the Apostle (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_the_Apostle)

[How old was the apostle Paul when he died?](https://www.reference.com/world-view/old-apostle-paul-died-d738346c9cfd066c#)

[Saint Paul the Apostle (Catholic Saints Info.)](http://catholicsaints.info/saint-paul-the-apostle/)

[St. Paul (Catholic Online)](http://www.catholic.org/saints/saint.php?saint_id=91)

Answer (score 1):

From [answers.com](http://www.answers.com/Q/How_Old_was_the_Apostle_Paul_when_he_was_converted?#slide=11):

> Paul never mentions his age in the Bible; however, what is known is this: He was a 'young man' when he persecuted Jesus [see Acts 7:58], right up to the point of his conversion in 36 C.E. By Jewish standards of the time, as according to the Mishna, a young man is one who is 30 or older, so at the time of his conversion . . . [Paul could] have been anywhere between six years younger or 24 years older than Jesus.
>
> However, he also mentions in his letters that in 55 C.E. he was an “old man” [Philemon 1:9; see also, for example, Romans 16:23; 2 Timothy 4:6-8; and 1 Corinthians 4:15 for hints about Paul's age] and by those day’s standards an old man was 60 or older. In addition to some other scholarly speculation . . . his birth date is probably unknowable, but . . . [some scholars assume] he was born probably around 5 C.E., making him slightly younger than Jesus.

Tradition has it that Paul died in Rome as a martyr. With the above information as a basis of calculation, the year of his death could perhaps be between A.D. 62 and A.D. 67. (For further helpful information, see [this chart](http://www.bombaxo.com/paulchron.html)).